# JS slide show with fadeToggle

Tags: slideshow, fadein

I have a basic slideshow function as shown below, but to make it smoother I would like to use the FadeIn/Out/Toggle to transition between the images. I have tried various ways of inserting this JS function but cannot get it to work.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var curimg=0
    function rotateimages(){
        document.getElementById("slideshow").setAttribute("src", "images/homepage_images/"+galleryarray[curimg]);
        curimg=(curimg<galleryarray.length-1)? curimg+1 : 0;
    }

    window.onload=function(){
        setInterval("rotateimages()", 3500)
    }
</script>
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Managed to resolve this by adding the attribute as a function of fadeout().

Answer (score 0):

Managed to resolve this by adding the attribute as a function of fadeout().